# deploy source to org in salesforce

Tags: deployment, salesforce, apex-trigger

I tried to deploy an apex trigger to my salesforce org
and I got this error:
"Invalid type: Schema.Language_Course__c "

the apex file:
"trigger LanguageCourseTrigger on Language_Course__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {
System.debug('Hello');
}"
what can I do?

Comment: Is there a custom object `Language_Course__c` created in the target org? If there isn't - you'll have to create/deploy it too. Are you sure you don't have typos in the object's name?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ther is no more question
the custom object Language_Course__c was missing 
I added it and it's work
Tanks for your answer